# Is Oracle Intermedia still actual?

Tags: database, oracle

I’m currently reading the 1st edition of Thomas Kyte’s book about DBMS Oracle. And I wonder to know is Oracle Intermedia still relevant in new versions of DBMS?

Comment: In a book that old, very little will still be relevant. What version of the database is it about?

Comment: @pmdba 8 version.

Comment: Oracle 8 has been obsolete for 25 years, and the technology has changed a *lot*. Look for anything on Oracle 19c or 21c for current versions as of 2022.